# Matrix gauss continuation

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have the matrix $4\times4$, $R_1 =(0,0,1,1)$, $R_2=(0,1,1,0)$, $R_3=(1,1,0,0)$, $R_4(1,0,0,0)$ and suppose we want to see the rank.The difficult part is that you cannot order them somehow to use gauss.Any ideas what should be done in such situations?

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract any row from any other without changing the rank:
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1&1\\0&1&1&0\\1&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\sim\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1&1\\0&1&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\sim\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1&1\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\sim\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
So the rank is full.

You can also reorder the rows at the beginning as this doesn't change the rank:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\1&1&0&0\\0&1&1&0\\0&0&1&1\end{pmatrix}$$
and continue as before.

Comment: Is there a rule to know that whatever I do next I won't change anything?

Comment: @Kris There are more rules, but first I'd like to ask what's your definition of the rank of a matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Re-ordering the rows does not change the rank. We can therefore consider the matrix 
$$
A
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&0\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&0&1&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Clearly $\det A=1$ so $A$ has rank four.

Of course, this method does not generalize to matrices with rows that are "less nice".

Comment: yes true but what if we have 6 equations :D

Comment: here it is pretty simple i gave an bad example

Comment: @Kris 6 rows? This would depend on the size of the rows! If you had six rows of length six, then this method could conceivably work. Possibly not, though, which is why I added my last sentence.

Comment: no 6 rows lenght 4 :D

Comment: @Kris, well this method may still work since the rank is equal to the size of the largest minor with nonzero determinant. 

It sounds to me though that your question may simply be too general for a satisfactory answer.